# AngularJS get success message from http post module

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer in a contact page with angular `$scope`. I have been sent email but I didn't get any message in the contact page.

Contact Page Form:

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="sendContact()" name="contactform" id="contactform" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label for="name" accesskey="U" ng-bind-html="contact.hname"></label>
            <input  type="text"  name="contactName" id="contactName" required ng-model="contactName"  />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="email" accesskey="E" ng-bind-html="contact.hemail">
                <span>*</span>
            </label>
            <input required id="contactEmail" name="contactEmail" type="email" ng-model="contactEmail"  pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="comments" accesskey="C" ng-bind-html="contact.hmessage">
                <span>*</span>
            </label>
            <textarea required id="contactText" name="contactText" cols="40" rows="3"  spellcheck="true" ng-model="contactMessage" ></textarea>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" ng-bind-html="contact.send" ng-disabled="submitButtonDisabled" />
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <p ng-class="contact.result" style="padding: 15px; margin: 0;" ng-bind-html="contact.sendContactResult"></p>
    <span style="color: green;" ng-bind-html="contact.sendContactResult"></span>
    <p ng-show='contact.send' style="padding: 15px; margin: 0;"></p>
</form>
```

Controller

```
$scope.sendContact = function(){
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'admin/api/mailer/contact.php',
        data: { 
            name: $scope.contactName, 
            email: $scope.contactEmail, 
            message: $scope.contactMessage,
        },  //param method from jQuery
        headers : { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
        }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
    }).success(function(r) {
        toastr.success("Eposta adresiniz sistemimize başarıyla kaydedildi.");
        console.log(data);
        $scope.contact.sendContactResult = $sce.trustAsHtml("Mesajınız başarıyla iletildi.");
        if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
            $scope.contact.sendContactResult = $sce.trustAsHtml("Mesajınız başarıyla iletildi.");
            $scope.contact.send = false;
            $scope.contact.sendContactResult = $sce.trustAsHtml("Message has been sent");
            $scope.contact.result = 'bg-success';
        }
        else {
            $scope.contact.sendContactResult = $sce.trustAsHtml("Message no sent");
            $scope.contact.result = 'bg-success';
        }
    });
};
```

PhpMailer = contact.php

```
$data= file_get_contents("php://input");
$dataJsonDecode = json_decode($data);
$name = $dataJsonDecode->name;
$email = $dataJsonDecode->email;
$message = $dataJsonDecode->message;

include 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'mail.mhz.com.tr';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'xxx';
$mail->Password = 'xxx';
$mail->SetFrom($mail->Username, $name);
$mail->AddAddress('xxx','INFO');
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Subject = 'xxxxx';
//$mail->MsgHTML('$a');
$mail->Body = "Name: " . $name . "\r\n\r\nEmail:".$email."\r\n\r\nMessage: " . stripslashes($message);

if ($mail->Send()) 
{
    echo 'Mail sent!';
} 
else 
{
    echo 'Mail error ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

$data = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Thanks! We have received your message.');
echo json_encode($data);
```

I am receiving the email. Everything is ok but I can't get the `success` message in the contact form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the angular toaster, it will require two params as:

```
 toastr.success("Success", "Eposta adresiniz sistemimize başarıyla kaydedildi.");
```

if its an error, then

```
toastr.error("Error", "Error Message.");
```

If its a custom toaster, then you would need to check your app module for it.

Comment: Not working toastr.http post page refresh in each message .

Comment: What do you mean? Please elaborate.

Comment: When I click send button then mail sent and page refreshes but I cant get any success message

Comment: Not helpful at all. Debug code to find out which code line gives error.